# What is the time complexity of finding the FIRST and FOLLOW sets?

Tags: time-complexity, parsers

Given how important these are for parsing, I'm surprised I wasn't able
to find anything about their complexity. I'm interested in all combinations of:

What is the (edit: best known) time complexity of calculating
<FIRST | FOLLOW | FIRST and FOLLOW> of a <single | all> nonterminals of a <context-free | LR> grammar?

Links to resources or partial answers are welcome.

Comment: `I'm surprised I wasn't able to find anything about their complexity` add me to the list (of surprised ones). What resources *did* you consult, and how?

Comment: @greybeard Materials from a my univerity's course on parsing (which only mentioned complexity of parsing algorithms, not of generating tables, or I missed someting), and Google. I found lots of tutorials about how to compute them, but no mention of complexity. Interestingly, now that I try googling it this question shows up zeroth :)

Comment: After rereading the text in a search for citations, I realised that I had made an egregious error in the answer; I have now fixed it and I offer my deepest apologies for my faulty memory. (The error was to leave out a factor of $|T|$ for the all-terminals cases, which comes in because set union is not $O(1)$.) The absence of web-searchable resources is probably because all of the essential research in this question is pre-internet, and most of it is behind paywalls erected by the pirates of the academic high seas. (How can it be reasonable to charge US$40 for a 40-year-old six-page paper?)

Comment: @rici thank you for the correction and the thorough answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbf{first}_1$ and $\mathbf{follow}_1$ as relations over the symbols of a grammar $\mathcal{G}$ can be computed for a given non-terminal in $\Theta(|\mathcal{G}|)$, wnere the size of $\mathcal{G}$ is defined in a an intuitive way (basically, the sum of the lengths of the productions).

It's clear that $|\mathcal{G}|$ is a lower limit since no algorithm could work without considering every symbol of every production of the grammar. An algorithm which takes time linear to the size of the grammar (with a proof of time complexity) is provided in section 5.5 of [*Parsing Theory, Vol. 1* (S. Sippu & E. Soisalon-Soininen, 1988)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/book/10.5555/48796). (If $k\gt 1$, a polynomial term is introduced because of the size of the $FIRST_k$ sets.)

Thus, to compute the entire relation requires $O(|\mathcal{G}|\cdot|T|)$, where $T$ is the set of terminal symbols in $\mathcal{G}$. The $|T|$ factor (which could, in the worst case, be $O(|\mathcal{G}|)$) is the result of having to perform set union operations on sets of up to $|T|$ elements. In practice, there is no advantage to attempting to compute the $FIRST$ and $FOLLOW$ sets for an individual non-terminal; there is a lot of overlap in the individual computations.

These results were not new; the bibliography credits Donald B. Johnson & Ravi Sethi (1976) [*A characterisation of LL(1) grammars*](https://arizona.pure.elsevier.com/en/publications/a-characterization-of-ll1-grammars), but a paywall impedes my verification. The algorithms are also cited in Hunt, Szymanski & Ullman (1977) [*Operations on Sparse Relations*](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/359436.359446), which refers to a 1974 paper by the same authors, with roughly the same name (paywalled, but you might be able to find it).

By way of a side note, the framework of relational expressions developed and used by Sippu & Soisalon-Soininen throughout the two volumes of *Parsing Theory* is a thing of beauty which for me was sufficient to justify my investment in the textbook. But you might be able to find it in a good academic library.